# Android Studio Do not display encode utf 8 characters

Tags: android-studio, utf-8, encode

See here.

[image]

But!!!

[image]

where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the font that Android Studio uses for the editor (File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to :

> File >> Settings >> Editor >> Colors & Fonts >> Font

When your Android Studio uses the **Default Scheme** you Can't Edit the Font in **Editor Font** Section

> 1 : Save as the **Default Scheme** by Every Name you Want

Now You Can Pick a Font

> 2 : Unchecked the **Show only monospaced font**
>   3 : in **Primary Font** Spinner , Chose **Tahoma**
>   4 : Set **Size** and **Line Spacing** You Want
>   5 : Apply and Ok

[image: I M A G E]

Comment: Thank you, Iranians are the best

Answer (score 2):

Here is how my strings values were shown properly.
In android studio, got to file menu.
Click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart...**.

Don't forget to upvote.