# Android Studio not displaying unicode characters

Tags: android-studio, colors, color-scheme

I recently updated my Android Studio to v3.4. Now the unicode characters I had earlier used, is not displayed on the editor screen. I can see them on the app, but not in the code.
Check the screenshot for more idea.

In the strings.xml, layouts anywhere it is not displayed. I tried to change the color scheme, tried with a new profile, none worked.

[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403133/android-studio-do-not-display-encode-utf-8-characters

Comment: @mahbubzaman got it . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In android studio, got to file menu.
Click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart...**.

That will show up the strings properly.
Don't forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to see Hindi Unicode**

First You Download Poppins Font [Download font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins)

Then Open Android Studio

File > Settings > Editor > Font > [(Untick) Show only monospaced fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmIVp.png)  > Select Font > Poppins Light or Medium > Click OK Button

Result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL2UJ.png)

Answer (score -1):

Go to your `res/strings.xml` and add the following code:

```
<string name="fgmt_titre_drawer">YourText</string>
```

Then rebuild your project.